# How rt.jar loaded in jvm - hotspot?

Tags: jvm-hotspot

I'm learning how the jvm works. Now I'm trying to figure out at what point to run rt.the jar is loaded into the VM. And where in the code can I see it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you actually mean by *'rt.jar is loaded into the VM'*. HotSpot does not *load* the entire `rt.jar` in memory. Instead, it looks for a corresponding JAR entry lazily whenever the bootstrap class loader tries to load a class. Sometimes the JVM does not even need to access jar to load a system class, e.g. when using a [CDS archive](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/vm/class-data-sharing.html). Also note, there is no longer `rt.jar` since JDK 9 - there are [modular images](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) instead.

A simple way to find when/where the JVM first opens `rt.jar` - is to run Java under a debugger and set a breakpoint at `ZIP_Open`.

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff5632880 in ZIP_Open () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff5632880 in ZIP_Open () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
#1  0x00007ffff67d65cb in ClassLoader::create_class_path_entry(char const*, stat const*, bool, bool, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007ffff67d6ba1 in LazyClassPathEntry::open_stream(char const*, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007ffff67d8b99 in ClassLoader::load_classfile(Symbol*, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007ffff6e32e9f in SystemDictionary::load_instance_class(Symbol*, Handle, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007ffff6e3397e in SystemDictionary::resolve_instance_class_or_null(Symbol*, Handle, Handle, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x00007ffff6e34f93 in SystemDictionary::initialize_wk_klasses_until(SystemDictionary::WKID, SystemDictionary::WKID&, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#7  0x00007ffff6e35165 in SystemDictionary::initialize_preloaded_classes(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#8  0x00007ffff6e355a8 in SystemDictionary::initialize(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#9  0x00007ffff6e84928 in Universe::genesis(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#10 0x00007ffff6e8596c in universe2_init() () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#11 0x00007ffff69d5248 in init_globals() () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#12 0x00007ffff6e6a38d in Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*) () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#13 0x00007ffff6aae50f in JNI_CreateJavaVM () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#14 0x00007ffff79aefa0 in JavaMain () from /usr/java/jdk8u275/bin/../lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
#15 0x00007ffff7bc6e65 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#16 0x00007ffff74d388d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Here we see the exact stack trace, where the JVM first opens `rt.jar`. This happens during the JVM bootstrap, when initializing the system dictionary, to preload a system class.

Now it's easy to find these functions in the [source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/tip).
[classLoader.cpp](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/540c4d715391/src/share/vm/classfile/classLoader.cpp) is a good place to start from.